# Where should this component be in Deployment Diagram

Tags: uml, deployment

I have a quick question.
Imagine this scenario:
There is a webapp in server X. There is also another component (file) in server Y.
In the webapp, starting, it does:

```
<script src="component from server Y">
```

Should I place the component from server Y in the server Y, or inside the WebApp component, in the Deployment diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deployment diagram shows where the various artifacts must be located in a live system in order for the system to operate.

For your system to operate, the "component from server Y" must be deployed to the server that is referenced by the URL in the script tag. This is presumably server Y, so the deployment diagram should reflect that.

Additionally, it can be helpful to indicate that the WebApp component has a dependency on this "component from server Y".